# How to get the sum of all Double values in a tuples array?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

This is my function and I am trying to get the sum of all the Double values. I tried using += but I got many errors, I would really appreciate any assistance!

```
 func getSum(myList: [(title: String, id: Int, value: Double)]) -> Double {
    
    var key = Double()

    for i in 0..<myList.count {
         //something over here needs to change
        key = myList[i].value
        
    }

     
    
    return key
}


let myList: [(String, Int, Double)] = [("A", 1, 1.5), ("B", 2, 2.5), ("C", 3, 3.5)] // should return 7.5 (1.5 + 2.5 + 3.5)
```

Comment: What you are doing right now with `key = myList[i].value` is assigning the value to `key` at each iteration and so in the last `iteration` it gets the value 3.5 and that is what you see. You instead need to add it at each iteration `key += myList[i].value` is what you need.

Comment: `+=` should work without any issues for your situation. I tried it on my side and works as it should.

Comment: Thanks again! I was using it with the same variable so that's why it didn't work :0

Answer (score 2):

`Map` the tuple to its `value` value and sum it up with `reduce`.

```
func getSum(myList: [(title: String, id: Int, value: Double)]) -> Double {
    return myList.map(\.value).reduce(0.0, +)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getSum(myList: [(title: String, id: Int, value: Double)]) -> Double {

var key = Double()

for i in 0..<myList.count {
    key = key + myList[i].value
}

return key
}


let myList: [(String, Int, Double)] = [("A", 1, 1.5), ("B", 2, 2.5), ("C", 3, 3.5)]

print(getSum(myList:myList));   **//Output 7.5**
```